# Issue with NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults not clearing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, nsuserdefaults, facebook-ios-sdk

So I am using the `NSUserDefaults` to store my `FBAccessTokenKey` and `FBExpirationDateKey`. I am creating a singleton User object:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
         facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];

         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
            && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"] ) {
            NSLog(@"ACCESS KEY IS NOT EMPTY");
            facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
         } else {
              NSLog(@"ACCESS KEY IS EMPTY");
         }


    }
    return self;
}
```

I also have implemented a didLogout method that is called when I logout:

```
- (void)fbDidLogout {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
```

This basically clears/flushes out the token key. 
Now the real issue is that when I click on logout, quit the app, and then run the app again, it detects that the key `FBAccessTokenKey` and `FBExpirationDateKey` is still there. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should call: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` before exit